# Where can I get PLinq for VS 2008?

Tags: .net-3.5, plinq

Since it's integration to the framework, the package seems to have been removed from the web. can someone point me to a download site where i can download it and use it with my .net 3.5 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CTP is no longer available. From Nuget:

> This backport was shipped with the Reactive Extensions (Rx) library up
>   until v1.0.2856.0.

You can download an unsupported version from the Reactive Extensions for .Net at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24940 or from Nuget at http://nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary

Answer (score 2):

Is this link helpfull: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=348F73FD-593D-4B3C-B055-694C50D2B0F3&displaylang=en

It is the CTP version.

Regards,

Jochen